# How to make client connect to a first random port, without specifying it - Java

Tags: java, tcp, client-server, port

I have a server listening on a port, and i want client to connect to it without knowing its number. How can do it in java?

Comment: You can't. TCP/IP connections require an IP address and a port number.

Comment: Guess what port to use?

Comment: Try them all?  There's only 65,535.

Comment: Or, you know **choose** a port and use that. There's absolutely no reason you should be guessing.

Comment: When i look at it now, my question might be misleading. I want a client to connect to a random (no matter which one) open port on server. Not specific port.

Comment: Just choose a random port (from a list?) using `Random()`, and connect to it.

Comment: And what about ports that are already bound? For instance 80 or 22. There must be better way.

Answer (score 2):

Only way to do it is try them all. There are 65,535 different ports.

But I **strongly** discourage you from doing it.